# mongodb query documents older than x days, and none created since

Tags: mongodb

I have documents that look like this:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('1234'),
    name: 'Some name',
}
```

How do I write a query that will return the documents where _id was created more than 60 days ago (according to the generation time in the ObjectId), and no documents with that same name have been created since. Then I would like to filter down to only the documents with a distinct name.

Edit: Ok, if the document now looks like this, how do I achieve the results I am looking for?

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('1234'),
    name: 'Some name',
    created: Datetime()
}
```

Comment: Honestly, I suggest you to use a datetime instead. The answer below is perfect but it's too hard to use this method based on ObjectId.

Comment: So I'm confused, your edited document has a time stamp in it (created:Datetime)? Or that info was not put into the document.

Comment: Yeah my original document did not have the 'created' field. Listening to Maximiliano Rios and Sergey Eremin I added it.

Answer (score 0):

```
> db.foo.findOne()._id.getTimestamp
function (){
return new Date(parseInt(this.valueOf().slice(0,8), 16)*1000);
}
```

This is the source of the shell helper function `getTimestamp` which does what you want. But it is impossible to use it in a query. Mongo can not work with 16-base numbers in a query or convert them to 10-base numbers.

You will have to get the *whole* collection and do that conversion in your app if you really want to use `_id` as a source of time. You should definitely add a time field to each document to do get documents' age.